# C++ inherited copy constructor call ?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, copy-constructor

I have class B derived from class A. I call copy constructor that I implemented myself for an object of class B. I also implemented myself a constructor for class A.

Is this copy constructor automatically called when I call copy constructor for class B ? Or how to do this ? Is this the good way:

```
A::A(A* a)
{
    B(a);
    // copy stuff
}
```

thanks!

Comment: That's not a copy constructor.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this with a constructor initialization list, which would look like this:

```
B::B(const B& b) : A(b)
{
    // copy stuff
}
```

I modified the syntax quite a bit because your code was not showing a copy constructor and it did not agree with your description.

Do not forget that if you implement the copy constructor yourself you should follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Comment: ...or rule of five, if writing C++11 (which one should already be writing).

Answer (score 6):

A copy constructor has the signature:

```
A(const A& other)  //preferred
```

or

```
A(A& other)
```

Yours is a conversion constructor. That aside, you need to explicitly call the copy constructor of a base class, otherwise the default one will be called:

```
B(const B& other) { }
```

is equivalent to

```
B(const B& other) : A() { }
```

i.e. your copy constructor from class A won't be automatically called. You need:

```
B(const B& other) : A(other) { }
```